# Updating multiple *json files from *.txt file

Tags: javascript, json, scripting

I have several json files, each file contains the following line

```
"description": "Example",
```

I need to update this field in each json file with a line from the text file, as an example the text file has the following, each contained on a separate line.

Blue Jeans

Red Jacket

Hat

Shirt

Floral Dress

Wollen Jacket

Green belt

Shoes

Orange Shirt

Belt

I'm trying to see if there is a way or script that for each json file to go through the text file and update the description field, 1.json file would return line item 1 from the text file etc and work its way through until completed, 10.json would update with line item 10 from the *.txt file etc

ie file 3.json would have `"description": "Example",` updated to `"description": "Hat",`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to read each file, parse it, then update what you need to update and then finally write it back to disk again.
Here my `test.js` script:

```js
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises";

async function replaceInFiles(){
  const replacements = ["Blue Jeans", "Red Jacket", "Hat", "Shirt", "Floral Dress", "Wollen Jacket", "Green belt", "Shoes", "Orange Shirt", "Belt"]
  await Promise.all(replacements.map(async (replaceWith, idx) => {
    const filename = `${idx + 1}.json`;
    // read file
    let file;
    try {
      file = await readFile(filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Failed to read ${filename}. ${error}`)
      return;
    }
    // parse content
    const parsed = JSON.parse(file);
    // replace description
    parsed.description = replaceWith;
    // write updated file with intendation of 4
    try {
      await writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 4));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Failed to write ${filename}. ${error}`)
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Updated ${filename}.`);
  }));
  console.log("Done.")
}

(async () => {
  await replaceInFiles();
})();
```

I have tested it with to files:

`1.json`

```json
{ "description": "Example" }
```

`2.json`

```json
{ "description": "Example2" }
```

Then I run the script using `node test.js` and this result in the following:

`Console`

```
Failed to read 3.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '3.json'
Failed to read 4.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '4.json'
Failed to read 5.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '5.json'
Failed to read 6.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '6.json'
Failed to read 7.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '7.json'
Failed to read 9.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '9.json'
Failed to read 8.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '8.json'
Failed to read 10.json. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '10.json'
Updated 1.json.
Updated 2.json.
Done.
```

`1.json`

```json
{
    "description": "Blue Jeans"
}
```

`2.json`

```
{
    "description": "Red Jacket"
}
```

#### Edit

As you've mentioned in the comment you want to read the `replacements` from a text file here what you need to add to the previous code.

`replacements.txt`

```
Blue Jeans
Red Jacket
Hat
Shirt
Floral Dress
Wollen Jacket
Green belt
Shoes
Orange Shirt
Belt
```

Here the code to populate the `replacements` array given you have above file with every element being on a new line as you've described in your comment:

```js
const replacementStr = await readFile("replacements.txt", { encoding: "utf8" });
const replacements = replacementStr.split("\n");
// to make the split work for any OS no matter the line endings you can use
const replacements = replacementStr.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Mushroomator much appreciated!

This worked well,  I was hoping to be able to read a text file for the updates however as I will have 400+ json files I need to update and I already have them separated by line item in a text file. Would like to avoid placing them against `const replacements =` if I can.

Sorry I should have mentioned this initially, was trying to just capture the scenario I'm faced with.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you again :)

This also worked but for some reason there is a /r being added to each description.

ie `"description": "Green belt\r",` or `"description": "Orange Shirt\r",`

I'm not sure where this is coming from?

Comment: This has to do with line endings different operating systems use. You should read [this](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/crlf-vs-lf-normalizing-line-endings-in-git/#crlf-vs-lf-what-are-line-endings-anyway) in order to understand what's happening. To resolve this you can use the Regex approach described in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-split-by-newline). It's for Java but the Regex should work in JavaScript as well.

Comment: The JavaScript equivalent would be `replacementStr.split(/\r?\n|\r/)` which you should use. This matches either `\r` (optional) and `\n` or just `\r`.